# How to limit the length of an array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

Is there any way to add a constraint on a column that is an array to limit it's length? I want these arrays to be no longer than 6. And yes, I understand that often a new table is better than storing in an array but I am in a situation where an array makes more sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a `CHECK` constraint to the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id  serial PRIMARY KEY,
    arr int[] CHECK (array_length(arr, 1) < 7),
    ...
);
```

If the table already exists, you can add the constraint with `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT arr_len CHECK (array_length(arr, 1) < 7);
```

Comment: Since 9.4 you can also use `cardinality(arr)` instead